# How to profile a C++ program and replay its variables?

Tags: c++, debugging, profiling

[birdseye](https://birdseye.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is a Python debugger which records the values of expressions in a function call and lets you easily view them after the function exits.

What is a similar tool to replay for C++ programs?

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what platform you're using and what sort of profiling you want to do.

On Windows, you can use the Visual Studio profiler. This will let you see how much time is spent in each function, and also let you see the values of variables at different points in the program's execution.

On Linux, you can use the gprof profiler. This will give you similar information to the Visual Studio profiler, but for Linux programs.

If you want to profile your program's memory usage, you can use Valgrind. This will let you see how much memory is being used by your program, and where that memory is being allocated.